# CLion: Swift - "Executable is not specified"

Tags: swift, clion, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to play around with server-side Swift on MacOS High Sierra using CLion as my IDE.  I have installed the Swift plugin, along with the Swift development toolchain.  I can create a Swift project successfully, but when I go to "Run" to execute the program, I see an error message saying, "`Error: Executable is not specified`".  The Executable pull-down menu doesn't list anything.  It just says, "Select other..."

I haven't touched any of the files created when I created the Swift project.  Is there something else I need to do to get this executable to run?  My Build appears to go fine, but I still don't see the Executable pull-down menu populated.

Comment: I could be wrong but don't you need to run AppCode to do Swift in the JetBrains universe?

Comment: Allegedly you should be able to use CLion for server-side Swift development.  AppCode is for mobile app development.

Comment: AppCode also works for us Mac users, not just mobile ;-) I only played a little with Kitura using a normal text editor in my server side efforts, a CLion solution would be nicer.  +1 from me for an interesting coding possibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i've did a simple hack that worked for me my OS is like yours {Mac os 10.13.1 } i'm using clion 2017.2.3

1- build your project like normal, if it was built right the executable with what ever name you gave it will be at directory 
***/project/.build/debug/executable***

2- the .build directory is hidden so you need to unhide it (the . at the start of directory or file name is forbidden so you can't unhide it), i've created an alias and change it's name to {some name with no . before it}

3- know go to clion->edit configuration->Executable->select other.
know go to the alias folder that you've created and choose the executable at 
***/project/newbuild/debug/executable***

Comment: This is the exact problem I'm having.  So annoying.  Your workaround gets me around the issue, though.  Thanks!